# php split string based on words

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a PHP string like so

```
$string = 'Nunc sagittis in orci in pharetra. Mauris orci mauris, tincidunt in nisi quis, bibendum facilisis lectus. Sales Center Hours Donec nec tristique neque. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras sit amet mauris lorem.';
```

I am trying to split this string into 2 (array is acceptable) I am trying to split so my first string has everything before Sale Centre Hours and the second string has Sale Centre Hours and everything after that.

Comment: did you try regular expression to solve your problem/?

Comment: I suck at regular expressions

Comment: @user979331: Then now is a good time to learn... wouldn't you agree?

Comment: This is not difficult. You have a brain for a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking at something like this for result? If yes, you could use the following code:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Nunc sagittis in orci in pharetra. Mauris orci mauris, tincidunt in nisi quis, bibendum facilisis lectus. 
    [1] => Sales Center Hours Donec nec tristique neque. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras sit amet mauris lorem. 
)
```

Code for this:

```
<?php
$string = 'Nunc sagittis in orci in pharetra. Mauris orci mauris, tincidunt in nisi quis, bibendum facilisis lectus. Sales Center Hours Donec nec tristique neque. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras sit amet mauris lorem.';

$split_by = 'Sales Center Hours';
$split_data = explode($split_by, $string);
$split_data[1] = $split_by . $split_data[1];
print_r ($split_data);
?>
```

If $split_by is not found in the text, that can give us unexpected results. To manage that gracefully, you may do something like this:

```
<?php
$string = 'Nunc sagittis in orci in pharetra. Mauris orci mauris, tincidunt in nisi quis, bibendum facilisis lectus. Sales Center Hours Donec nec tristique neque. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras sit amet mauris lorem.';

$split_by = 'Bad text';
$split_data = explode($split_by, $string);

// confirm that the string was split into two. If it did, 
// add the split_by text to the front of the 2nd item (index 1)
if (count($split_data) === 2) {
    $split_data[1] = $split_by . $split_data[1];
}

// do something with the text
print_r ($split_data);
?>
```

Comment: this did not work: Undefined offset: 1

Comment: @user979331 I have added a defensive means to handle the code that may give you undefined offset

Answer (score 1):

Regexp version

```
preg_match( '/(.*)\s+(Sales Center Hours.*)/', $string, $matches );

echo( $matches[1] ); // before
echo( $matches[2] ); // after
```

Comment: This did not work: Notice: Undefined offset: 1 and Notice: Undefined offset: 2

Comment: Well, I've checked it on the string you provided.

Comment: yes, your code is correct...how would I get this to work with a string with code inside of it, say <h2

Comment: Can you give an example of such string?

Answer (score 0):

Yo can use the php funtion split http://php.net/manual/es/function.split.php, you must identify  the pattern

Answer (score 0):

You can use explode the string and then add the string used to explode to array elements.

```
<?php
$stringToSplit = "Sales Center Hours";
$string = 'Nunc sagittis in orci in pharetra. Mauris orci mauris, tincidunt in nisi quis, bibendum facilisis lectus. Sales Center Hours Donec nec tristique neque. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras sit amet mauris lorem.';
$arr = explode($stringToSplit, $string);
$arr[1] = $stringToSplit . $arr[1];
print_r($arr)
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The "explode" function could do it.. something like the following :

```
$string = "Nunc sagittis in orci in pharetra. Mauris orci mauris, tincidunt in nisi quis, bibendum facilisis lectus. Sales Center Hours Donec nec tristique neque. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras sit amet mauris lorem.";
$separator="Sale Centre Hours";
$results=explode($separator,$string);
$firstString=$results[0];
$secondString=$separator.$results[1];
```